# Code is slow, and makes my excel crash sometimes

Tags: excel, vba

Code works as intended but feels sloppy and slow,and sometimes even crashes/freezes the instance of excel im running just wondering how i can make it more efficient, since im new to VBA and want to learn.

```
Option Explicit

Sub Acto_Export()
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    Dim SystemlistFilename As String
    Dim SystemlistSheetname As String
    Dim Wbk         As Workbook
    Dim Wsht        As Worksheet
    Set Wbk = ActiveWorkbook
    Set Wsht = Wbk.ActiveSheet
    Dim ProjectNumber As String
    Dim ProjectNummer As Integer
    Dim Activiteit  As Integer
    Dim ActiviteitNaam As Integer
    Dim ActiviteitSoort As Integer
    Dim Bouwdeel    As Integer
    Dim BouwdeelOmschrijving As Integer
    Dim BouwdeelZoeknaam As Integer
    Dim ActiviteitSoortNaam As Integer
    Dim ZoeknaamActiviteitSoort As Integer
    Dim Categorie   As Integer
    Dim CategorieNaam As Integer
    Dim Projectdeel As Integer
    Dim indIMP      As Integer
    Dim indEXP      As Integer
    Dim ACTOFileName As String
    Dim ACTOSheetName As String
    Dim ExportFileName As String
    Dim sFolder     As String
    ProjectNumber = Wsht.Cells(4, 3)
    SystemlistFilename = ActiveWorkbook.Name
    SystemlistSheetname = ActiveSheet.Name
    ExportFileName = sFolder & "\" & Format(Now, "yyyy-MM-dd_HHmmss_") & ProjectNumber & "_importfileActo.xlsx"
    ProjectNummer = 1
    Activiteit = 2
    ActiviteitNaam = 3
    ActiviteitSoort = 4
    Bouwdeel = 5
    BouwdeelOmschrijving = 6
    BouwdeelZoeknaam = 7
    ActiviteitSoortNaam = 8
    ZoeknaamActiviteitSoort = 9
    Categorie = 10
    CategorieNaam = 11
    Projectdeel = 12
    indIMP = 9
    indEXP = 2
    
    ' Get the project number from the active sheet
    With Application.FileDialog(msoFileDialogFolderPicker)
        If .Show = -1 Then        ' if OK is pressed
        sFolder = .SelectedItems(1)
    End If
End With
If sFolder = "" Then        ' if an error occured
MsgBox ("no folder was selected")
Exit Sub
End If

Workbooks.Add
ACTOFileName = ActiveWorkbook.Name
ACTOSheetName = ActiveSheet.Name

'Create Header
Workbooks(ACTOFileName).Worksheets(ACTOSheetName).Cells(1, ProjectNummer).Value = "project nummer"
Workbooks(ACTOFileName).Worksheets(ACTOSheetName).Cells(1, Activiteit).Value = "activiteit"
Workbooks(ACTOFileName).Worksheets(ACTOSheetName).Cells(1, ActiviteitNaam).Value = "activiteit naam"
Workbooks(ACTOFileName).Worksheets(ACTOSheetName).Cells(1, ActiviteitSoort).Value = "activiteit soort"
Workbooks(ACTOFileName).Worksheets(ACTOSheetName).Cells(1, Bouwdeel).Value = "bouwdeel"
Workbooks(ACTOFileName).Worksheets(ACTOSheetName).Cells(1, BouwdeelOmschrijving).Value = "bouwdeel omschrijving"
Workbooks(ACTOFileName).Worksheets(ACTOSheetName).Cells(1, BouwdeelZoeknaam).Value = "bouwdeel zoeknaam"
Workbooks(ACTOFileName).Worksheets(ACTOSheetName).Cells(1, ActiviteitSoortNaam).Value = "activiteit soort naam"
Workbooks(ACTOFileName).Worksheets(ACTOSheetName).Cells(1, ZoeknaamActiviteitSoort).Value = "zoeknaam activiteit soort"
Workbooks(ACTOFileName).Worksheets(ACTOSheetName).Cells(1, Categorie).Value = "categorie"
Workbooks(ACTOFileName).Worksheets(ACTOSheetName).Cells(1, CategorieNaam).Value = "categorie naam"
Workbooks(ACTOFileName).Worksheets(ACTOSheetName).Cells(1, Projectdeel).Value = "Projectdeel"

' Set number formats for specific columns
Workbooks(ACTOFileName).Worksheets(ACTOSheetName).Columns("B:L").Select
Selection.NumberFormat = "000000"
Workbooks(ACTOFileName).Worksheets(ACTOSheetName).Columns("I:I").Select
Selection.NumberFormat = "0"
Workbooks(ACTOFileName).Worksheets(ACTOSheetName).Columns("E:E").Select
Selection.NumberFormat = "0"
Workbooks(ACTOFileName).Worksheets(ACTOSheetName).Columns("J:J").Select
Selection.NumberFormat = "0"
Workbooks(ACTOFileName).Worksheets(ACTOSheetName).Columns("L:L").Select
Selection.NumberFormat = "0"

' Loop through data in the source sheet
While Workbooks(SystemlistFilename).Worksheets(SystemlistSheetname).Cells(indIMP, 2).Value <> ""
    
    Select Case LCase(Workbooks(SystemlistFilename).Worksheets(SystemlistSheetname).Cells(indIMP, 1).Value)
        Case ""
        Case "x"
        Case Else
            MsgBox ("Wrong value given. No file was created. please use X Error in row: ") & indIMP
            Workbooks(ACTOFileName).Close savechanges:=False
            Exit Sub
    End Select
    
    If Len(Workbooks(SystemlistFilename).Worksheets(SystemlistSheetname).Cells(4, 3).Value) <> "8" Then
        MsgBox ("Wrong value given. No file was created. please use a valid project number")
        Workbooks(ACTOFileName).Close savechanges:=False
        Exit Sub
    Else
    End If
    
    If WorksheetFunction.IsText(Workbooks(SystemlistFilename).Worksheets(SystemlistSheetname).Cells(4, 3).Value) Then
        MsgBox ("Wrong value given. No file was created. please use a valid project number")
        Workbooks(ACTOFileName).Close savechanges:=False
        Exit Sub
        
    Else
    End If
    
    If LCase(Workbooks(SystemlistFilename).Worksheets(SystemlistSheetname).Cells(indIMP, 1).Value) = "x" Then
        Workbooks(ACTOFileName).Worksheets(ACTOSheetName).Cells(indEXP, Activiteit).Value = "00" & Workbooks(SystemlistFilename).Worksheets(SystemlistSheetname).Cells(indIMP, 2).Value
        Workbooks(ACTOFileName).Worksheets(ACTOSheetName).Cells(indEXP, ActiviteitNaam).Value = Workbooks(SystemlistFilename).Worksheets(SystemlistSheetname).Cells(indIMP, 6).Value
        Workbooks(ACTOFileName).Worksheets(ACTOSheetName).Cells(indEXP, ProjectNummer).Value = Workbooks(SystemlistFilename).Worksheets(SystemlistSheetname).Cells(4, 3).Value
        Workbooks(ACTOFileName).Worksheets(ACTOSheetName).Cells(indEXP, ActiviteitSoort).Value = "00" & Workbooks(SystemlistFilename).Worksheets(SystemlistSheetname).Cells(indIMP, 2).Value
        Workbooks(ACTOFileName).Worksheets(ACTOSheetName).Cells(indEXP, Bouwdeel).Value = "0"
        Workbooks(ACTOFileName).Worksheets(ACTOSheetName).Cells(indEXP, BouwdeelOmschrijving).Value = "algemeen"
        Workbooks(ACTOFileName).Worksheets(ACTOSheetName).Cells(indEXP, BouwdeelZoeknaam).Value = "alg"
        Workbooks(ACTOFileName).Worksheets(ACTOSheetName).Cells(indEXP, ActiviteitSoortNaam).Value = Workbooks(SystemlistFilename).Worksheets(SystemlistSheetname).Cells(indIMP, 6).Value
        Workbooks(ACTOFileName).Worksheets(ACTOSheetName).Cells(indEXP, ZoeknaamActiviteitSoort).Value = Mid(Workbooks(SystemlistFilename).Worksheets(SystemlistSheetname).Cells(indIMP, 6).Value, 1, 2)
        Workbooks(ACTOFileName).Worksheets(ACTOSheetName).Cells(indEXP, Categorie).Value = "0"
        Workbooks(ACTOFileName).Worksheets(ACTOSheetName).Cells(indEXP, CategorieNaam).Value = "algemeen"
        Workbooks(ACTOFileName).Worksheets(ACTOSheetName).Cells(indEXP, Projectdeel).Value = "0"
        
        indEXP = indEXP + 1
    End If
    
    indIMP = indIMP + 1
    
Wend

' Rename the export sheet
Workbooks(ACTOFileName).Worksheets(ACTOSheetName).Name = "PLN961"
' Save the export file
Workbooks(ACTOFileName).SaveAs sFolder & ExportFileName

Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub
```

I tried my best to write it in a way that i think was logical, did some research (Hence the option explicit at the start, and screenupdating is turned off), and am now wondering what more of these small steps i can take t make my code more efficient

Comment: Did you try working with Calculation mode in manual?

Comment: How many rows  on the Systemlist sheet, >10k, > 100k ?

Comment: @FoxfireAndBurnsAndBurns nope... did not touch that, does that make a diffrence if im not doing any calculations? im basically only moving data from one sheet to another.

Comment: @CDP1802 The Systemlist Sheet is 9K rows

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You only need to check for a valid project number once not on every row. One way to speed up code is to copy data from sheet to an array and iterate that.

```vb
Option Explicit

Sub Acto_Export()
    
    Dim wb As Workbook, ws As Worksheet
    Dim SystemlistFilename As String, SystemlistSheetname
    Dim ProjectNumber As String
    Dim n As Long, r As Long, lastrow As Long
    Dim t0 As Single: t0 = Timer
    
    Set wb = ActiveWorkbook
    Set ws = wb.ActiveSheet
    
    SystemlistFilename = wb.Name
    SystemlistSheetname = ws.Name
    
    'Get the project number from the active sheet
    If WorksheetFunction.IsText(ws.Range("C4")) Or Len(ws.Range("C4")) <> 8 Then
         MsgBox ("Wrong value given. No file created. please use a valid project number in C4")
         Exit Sub
    End If
    ProjectNumber = ws.Range("C4")
    
    ' output column names
    Dim dictCol As Object
    Set dictCol = CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")
    With dictCol
        .Add "ProjectNummer", 1
        .Add "Activiteit", 2
        .Add "ActiviteitNaam", 3
        .Add "ActiviteitSoort", 4
        .Add "Bouwdeel", 5
        .Add "BouwdeelOmschrijving", 6
        .Add "BouwdeelZoeknaam", 7
        .Add "ActiviteitSoortNaam", 8
        .Add "ZoeknaamActiviteitSoort", 9
        .Add "Categorie", 10
        .Add "CategorieNaam", 11
        .Add "Projectdeel", 12
    End With
    
    ' initial rows
    Const indIMP = 9
    Const indEXP = 2
    
    Dim arList, arOut
    With ws
        ' array of list data
        lastrow = .Cells(.Rows.Count, 2).End(xlUp).Row
        arList = .Range("A1:F" & lastrow)
        ' array to hold output
        ReDim arOut(1 To lastrow, 1 To dictCol.Count)
    End With
      
    ' output header
    Dim arHeader
    arHeader = Array("Activiteit", "ActiviteitNaam", "ProjectNummer", _
        "ActiviteitSoort", "Bouwdeel", "BouwdeelOmschrijving", _
        "BouwdeelZoeknaam", "ActiviteitSoortNaam", "ZoeknaamActiviteitSoort", _
        "Categorie", "CategorieNaam", "Projectdeel")
        
    'Loop through data in the source sheet
    For r = indIMP To lastrow
            
        If LCase(arList(r, 1)) = "x" Then
            n = n + 1
            arOut(n, dictCol("Activiteit")) = "00" & arList(r, 2)
            arOut(n, dictCol("ActiviteitNaam")) = arList(r, 6)
            arOut(n, dictCol("ProjectNummer")) = "00" & ProjectNumber
            arOut(n, dictCol("ActiviteitSoort")) = "00" & arList(r, 2)
            arOut(n, dictCol("Bouwdeel")) = 0
            arOut(n, dictCol("BouwdeelOmschrijving")) = "algemeen"
            arOut(n, dictCol("BouwdeelZoeknaam")) = "alg"
            arOut(n, dictCol("ActiviteitSoortNaam")) = arList(r, 6)
            arOut(n, dictCol("ZoeknaamActiviteitSoort")) = Mid(arList(r, 6), 1, 2)
            arOut(n, dictCol("Categorie")) = 0
            arOut(n, dictCol("CategorieNaam")) = "algemeen"
            arOut(n, dictCol("Projectdeel")) = 0
        ElseIf Len(arList(r, 1)) > 0 Then
            MsgBox "Wrong value given. No file was created. please use X : ", _
                   vbExclamation, "Error in row " & r
              
            Exit Sub
        End If
        
    Next

    ' create output file
    Dim wbACTO As Workbook, wsACTO As Worksheet
    Dim sFolder As String, ExportFileName As String
    If n > 0 Then
        ' select output folder
        With Application.FileDialog(msoFileDialogFolderPicker)
            If .Show = -1 Then        ' if OK is pressed
                sFolder = .SelectedItems(1)
            End If
        End With
        If sFolder = "" Then        ' if an error occured
            MsgBox ("No folder was selected")
            Exit Sub
        End If
    
        ' create new workbook
        Set wbACTO = Workbooks.Add(1)
        Set wsACTO = wbACTO.Sheets(1)
        
        ' add header
        With wsACTO ' 12 colunms
            ' Rename the export sheet
            .Name = "PLN961"
            .Range("A1:L1") = arHeader
                           
            ' Set number formats for specific columns
            .Columns("B:K").NumberFormat = "000000"
            .Columns("E:E").NumberFormat = "0"
            .Columns("I:J").NumberFormat = "0"
            .Columns("L:L").NumberFormat = "0"
            
            ' write output
            .Cells(indEXP, 1).Resize(n, UBound(arOut, 2)) = arOut
        End With
        
        ' Save the export file
        ExportFileName = sFolder & "\" & Format(Now, "yyyy-MM-dd_HHmmss_") & ProjectNumber & "_importfileActo.xlsx"
        wbACTO.SaveAs ExportFileName
        MsgBox n & " rows written to " & ExportFileName, vbInformation, Format(Timer - t0, "0.0 secs ")
    Else
        MsgBox "No output to create", vbExclamation
    End If

End Sub
```

Comment: I'm going to use the Comment on checking project number once. that helps alot with the speed of the code.  after a few tests, this also stopped the crashing. i'm not going to use the array's, since i don't fully understand them, and i want to be able to fully understand my own code. thanks alot! Marked as answer

Comment: Update: learned Arrays as well, so used this to write my own array's into the program, and creation times have since never been above 5 sec... thanks again!

Comment: @anton Well done, it's worth the effort believe me, now you can move up to the next level [Dictionaries](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/language/reference/user-interface-help/dictionary-object) which are like arrays but with strings or numbers as the index.

Answer (score -1):

Beginning:

```vb
Application.EnableEvents = False 
Application.Calculation = xlManual
```

End:

```vb
Application.EnableEvents = True 
Application.Calculation = xlAutomatic
```

Comment: It would help to provide some commentary / context with your answer so that others can understand why you think this (fully ... or partly) answers the question asked.